# Getting wrong(?) average when calculating values in a time range

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working with AWS Redshift / PostgreSQL. I have two tables that can be joined on the `interval_date` (`DATE` data_type) and `interval_time_utc` (`VARCHAR` data type) and/or the `status` and `price_source` columns. `Source A` is equivalent to the `Y` status and `Source B` is equivalent to the `N` status. I am trying to get the average `price` and the sum of `mw_power` for a given hour for each `status` / `price_source`. An hour is the timestamps from XX:05 to XX:00 so for 15:00, the values should be from the 14:05 to the 15:00 timestamps. Even if for an hour interval where all status are one value, I still need to calculate the average `price` for both `price_source` values, but the sum of `mw_power` would be `0`. I am passing in the date and time intervals through my application code. I am seeing a different average price for the 15:00 hour than I expect so either I am bad at math or there is a bug in my query I can't determine. The 14:00 and 16:00 hour results come back as expected.

`power_table`

| interval_date | interval_time_utc | mw_power | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:00 | 92.25 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:05 | 90.75 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:10 | 91.25 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:15 | 92.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:20 | 92.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:25 | 90.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:30 | 93.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:35 | 91.75 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:40 | 90.25 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:45 | 93.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:50 | 91.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:55 | 94.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:00 | 91.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:05 | 91.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:10 | 94.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:15 | 92.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:20 | 91.00 | N |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:25 | 94.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:30 | 92.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:35 | 91.75 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:40 | 92.25 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:45 | 91.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:50 | 92.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:55 | 93.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-09 | 15:00 | 90.00 | Y |

`price_table`

| interval_date | interval_time_utc | price | price_source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:00 | 54.20 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:05 | 54.20 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:10 | 54.20 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:00 | 54.20 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:05 | 54.20 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:10 | 54.20 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:15 | 34.11 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:20 | 34.11 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:25 | 34.11 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:15 | 39.61 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:20 | 39.61 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:25 | 39.61 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:30 | 2.81 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:35 | 2.81 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:40 | 2.81 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:30 | 17.13 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:35 | 17.13 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:40 | 17.13 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:45 | 1.58 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:50 | 1.58 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:55 | 1.58 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:45 | 15.98 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:50 | 15.98 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:55 | 15.98 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:00 | 4.60 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:05 | 4.60 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:10 | 4.60 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:00 | 18.09 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:05 | 18.09 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:10 | 18.09 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:15 | 2.46 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:20 | 2.46 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:25 | 2.46 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:15 | 16.66 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:20 | 16.66 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:25 | 16.66 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:30 | 3.36 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:35 | 3.36 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:40 | 3.36 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:30 | 21.52 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:35 | 21.52 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:40 | 21.52 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:45 | 4.55 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:50 | 4.55 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:55 | 4.55 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:45 | 16.30 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:50 | 16.30 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:55 | 16.30 | Source B |
| 2022-05-09 | 15:00 | -21.87 | Source A |
| 2022-05-09 | 15:00 | 4.96 | Source B |

```
-- query that i am using to get hourly values
SELECT pricet.price_source,
       COALESCE(powert.volume, 0),
       pricet.price,
       powert.status
FROM (SELECT status,
             SUM(mw_power) volume
      FROM power_table
      WHERE (interval_date || ' ' || interval_time_utc)::timestamp BETWEEN '2022-05-09 14:05:00.0' AND '2022-05-09 15:00:00.0'
      GROUP BY status) powert
  RIGHT JOIN (SELECT price_source,
                     AVG(price) price
              FROM price_table
              WHERE (interval_date || ' ' || interval_time_utc)::timestamp BETWEEN '2022-05-09 14:05:00.0' AND '2022-05-09 15:00:00.0'
              GROUP BY price_source) pricet
  ON pricet.price_source = CASE WHEN powert.status = 'Y' THEN 'Source A'
                                ELSE 'Source B'
                           END;
```

I am looking to get an expected output of the following for the 15:00 hour:

| price_source | volume | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Source A | 736.00 | 0.54 | Y |
| Source B | 368.00 | 17.38 | N |

Result that I'm getting from query:

| price_source | volume | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Source A | 736.00 | 1.54 | Y |
| Source B | 368.00 | 17.05 | N |

db fiddle link of tables and query and results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=474b009c5cf5366961751a61c0f96c6c

Comment: Your data has the same value repeated at :00 and :05 and :10 , then a new value repeated at :15 and :20 and :25, and so on. Is that correct. In other words, please document ***precisely*** why you think the prices 0.54 and 17.08 are correct.

Comment: Example with extraneous price rows removed, then aggregated simply... (your manual maths is wrong, or your data is wrong) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ba0680a8fb40a69697d0ba50edae09d9

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a calculator error.  I changed your fiddle to add a rolling sum and rolling average for the second part of your query.  To get an average of .54 (Source A) your sum would need to be 12 less than the total of the values for this hour.  12 is the count of values for the hour so a possible slip in subtracting 12 before dividing by 12?

The other source (B) the total would need to be off by 4m (an addition of 4 to the sum).  Not sure how this could have happened but ...

Anyway the fiddle is at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e65c38677f3ab92607bbff778bc0f69e